# Silent authentication on Auth0 CORS error

Tags: cors, fetch, auth0, preflight

For a particular need, I need to do a silent authentication (prompt=none) on auth0 from the front and redirect response to my back. After that my back will exchange the authorization code to the Access Token and retrieve it to the front (this process is not common, but my problem focuses on the first request).

To implement this I use a "fetch" as follows:

```
const silentLoginUrl: string = 'https://xxx.us.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id='+client_id+'&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&scope=openid&state='+state+'&code_challenge='+code_challenge+'&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none';
fetch(silentLoginUrl, {
     method: 'GET',
     credentials: 'include',
     redirect: 'follow',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
     },
   })
```

I also configure auth0 with `http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:8080/, http://localhost:3000/callback` (8080 is my Single Page Application) in Allowed Web Origins and Allowed Origins (CORS).

But when I test I still get a CORS error on the preflight (OPTIONS) request :
404 : `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource`
`(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)`

And indeed there is no header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the response despite the auth0 configuration.

And if I directly execute the forged url in my browser everything works fine.

Have you encountered this type of error? Is it possible to make this call through a GET fetch?

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm having the exact same situation. While is not the best solution, what i found to work is to use "mode: 'no-cors'" in the fetch request.

With this, probably you will have the request return you a 302, but then probably you will start facing my actual problem, to actually redirect to have the access_token in the URL. fetch API seems to not be able to redirect interactive in the url.

Greetings, please let me know if you found another way, we need the same use case for making a silent auth in our app.

Comment: I found a page that says this is not possible [An “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” header for the “/authorize” endpoint](https://community.auth0.com/t/an-access-control-allow-origin-header-for-the-authorize-endpoint/13339). I guess it's for security reasons (other providers doing the same thing). For my part, I completely changed strategy and architecture to avoid this problem (by using a redirect, and no longer a fetch)

Comment: I just wanted to point out i ended doing the same, made a redirect to the authorize endpoint from an invisible iframe (the suggested standard way) and its working like a charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).